# how can I use history.pushState?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make history for my site but the tutorials wasn't useful too much.

the links doesn't work at all.

it is my js function:

```
function sendGet(url,des,dataform){
     //some ajax code...
     var stateObj = { state: 1 };
     history.pushState(stateObj, "", "?sendGet="+url+"@"+dataform);
return false;
}
sendGet("parts/login.php","","content")
```

for example when that function execute, this link has to set in browser history:

```
http://domain.com?sendGet=parts/login.php@content
```

any solution why my code is not working?

Comment: This may be helpful : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: "not working" is not very descriptive. What are you expecting?

Comment: @VaibhavJain I read that.

Comment: @WillPalmer I expect when I press back button, the browser location change to my link

Comment: Try with history.back();

Comment: The URL you give in your example is not valid (there should be a '/'before the qwuestion mark)

Answer (score 1):

Add a URL to the history stack with a specified state. 

Example:

```
history.pushState({ foo : "bar"}, "New title", "new-url.html")
```

Where the first argument is a state object.